# I am not able to use other packages in dependencies in flutter

Tags: flutter, plugins, directory, dependencies, package

I have just started using flutter and I am using flutter packages like material.dart , cupertino.dart but when it come to use other packages like image_picker, english_words, I am not able to use it and I had declared packages with versions in dependencies in pubsec.yaml file. After when I write the import package name in the main file it shows a red line under it and the folder was also not created on the left side.

Comment: If you got your question resolved, please accept the answer. If not resolved give more details so that we can both get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the packages that were declared as dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` files are not yet downloaded.

Try running: `flutter packages get` from your project's root directory.

Sometimes it doesn't work even after the above command is executed, in such case close current project and reopen it.